# I can't get my Discord bot in python to send messages to a specific channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, discord, discord.py

```py
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 101, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\PC0\Desktop\h ver 18-03\SmartBot-main\core\modules\greetings.py", line 6, in time_messege
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
NameError: name 'commands' is not defined
```

I get this error when referring to the discord bot, I am not quite clear about what I am doing wrong. Here is my code for that part:

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime


async def time_messege(args):
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
    alarmtime = "16:26"
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")
    #channel = bot.get_channel = xxx

    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if answer_num == 1:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
            if answer_num == 2:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?")
            if answer_num == 3:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
            elif answer_num == 4:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como se encuentran?")

            await time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            await time.sleep(10)
```

And I call this script in the main.py with this:

```py
import discord, json, os
import datetime, random, time

#Para poner mensajes por tiempo
from core.modules.greetings import time_messege
import threading
import asyncio

main_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

""" Load Bot Configurations """
config_path = os.path.join(main_path, "config.json")
with open(config_path, "r") as jsonfile:
    bot_config = json.load(jsonfile)

from core.smartbot import SmartBot
from core.modules.bot_brain import BotBrain
from core.modules.bot_actions import BotActions

bot_modules = [BotBrain, BotActions]
ChatBot = SmartBot(bot_config, bot_modules, main_path)

class BotClient(discord.Client):
    @staticmethod
    def is_DMChannel(message: str) -> bool:
        """Verifica si es un mensaje proveniente es de un canal privado"""
        return isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel)

    def save_log(self, response: str, message: object) -> None:
        """Guarda el historial de conversacion"""
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        file_path = os.path.join(main_path, f"assets/log/{date.strftime('%d%b%y')}.txt")

        with open(file_path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
            text_file.write(f"{message.content}\n{response}\n")

    def load_content(self, name: str) -> dict:
        """Carga contenido .json de la carpeta embeds"""
        embed_path = os.path.join(main_path, f"assets/embeds/{name}.json")
        with open(embed_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as jsonfile:
            content = json.load(jsonfile)

        return content

    def create_embed(self, content: dict) -> object:
        """Crea un embed basado en el contenido de un diccionario"""
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=content["title"],
            description=content["description"],
            color=int(content["color"], 16),
        )

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=content["icon_url"])

        for key, value in content["content"].items():
            embed.add_field(name=key, value=value, inline=content["inline"])

        embed.set_footer(text=content["footer"])

        return embed

    def create_response(self, message: object) -> list:
        """Crea una respuesta en base al mensaje, y le da formato usando embeds"""

        response = ChatBot(message.content, str(message.author.id))
        if response != "#NoText":
            embed_content = self.load_content("msg_container")

            face_images = self.load_content("icon_urls")
            state = ChatBot.user_data[str(message.author.id)]["state"]
            if state in face_images:
                embed_content["icon_url"] = face_images[state]
            else:
                embed_content["icon_url"] = random.choice(list(face_images.values()))

            embed_content["description"] = f"`{response}`"
            embed = self.create_embed(embed_content)
        else:
            embed = None
        return response, embed

    async def send_response(self, message: object, is_server=False) -> None:
        """Envia una respuesta por el canal de proveniencia del mensaje."""
        response, embed = self.create_response(message)
        if bot_config["DebugMode"]:
            self.save_log(response, message)
            print(f"{message.author}: {message.content}")
            print(f"@ Bot: {response}")

        if response and response != "#notext" and embed:
            if is_server:
                await message.reply(embed=embed)
            else:
                await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


    def between_callback(self, args):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        loop.run_until_complete(time_messege(args))
        loop.close()


    #Ese metodo se ejecuta automaticamente cada vez que el bot se enciende
    async def on_ready(self) -> None:

        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))

        #x = threading.Thread(target=time_messege) #Creo un thread independiente del main_thread
        #x.start()

        _thread = threading.Thread(target=self.between_callback, args=("some text", ))
        _thread.start()


    async def on_message(self, message: object) -> None:
        if not message.author.bot:
            if message.content.startswith(bot_config["prefix"]):
                args = message.content.split(" ", 1)
                command = args[0][len(bot_config["prefix"]):]

                if command.lower() == "fit":
                    ChatBot.fit(args[1], str(message.author.id))

            else:
                if self.is_DMChannel(message):
                    await self.send_response(message)

                elif not self.is_DMChannel(message) and self.user in message.mentions:
                    await self.send_response(message, is_server=True)


def ConsoleChat():
    """Permite utilizar al bot en la consola"""
    fake_user = "Anonimous"
    while True:
        text = input("User >> ")
        if text.lower() == "exit":
            break
        else:
            response = ChatBot(text, fake_user)
            if response != "#NoText":
                print(f"Bot: {response}")
            else:
                print("*Parece que el bot no quiere responder*")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BotClient().run(bot_config["BotToken"]) #Online para Discord
    #ConsoleChat()  #Offline desde Consola
```

But the error finds it in the class script

should I refer to the bot instance another way?
What should I do with this?

The error is in: bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

---

I import what they told me in the comments, and I can at least iterate once because it said "not yet", although then this error appeared, what do you think?

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Trace (most recent recent calls):
  File "C: \ Users \ PC0 \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run ()
  File "C: \ Users \ PC0 \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ threading.py", line 870, running
    self._target (* self._args, ** self._kwargs)
  File "main_greetings.py", line 101, in between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete (time_messege (arguments))
  File "C: \ Users \ PC0 \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ asyncio \ base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result ()
  File "C: \ Users \ PC0 \ Desktop \ h ver 18-03 \ SmartBot-main \ core \ modules \ greetings.py", line 36, at time_messege
    sleep timeout (10)
TypeError: NoneType object cannot be used in 'await' expression
```

This is the edited code but it give the error with await

```py
import time, random, discord
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands


async def time_messege(args):
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
    alarmtime = "9:01"
    greeting_channel = bot.get_channel("814238156396298310")
    #channel = bot.get_channel = xxx

    while True:
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            random_num = random.randint(1, 4)

            if answer_num == 1:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como estan chic@s?")
            if answer_num == 2:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que me cuentan?")
            if answer_num == 3:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, Como va su dia? que andan haciendo?")
            elif answer_num == 4:
                await greeting_channel.send("Holi!, como se encuentran?")

            await time.sleep(90)

        else:
            print("not yet")
            await time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply import it...

```py
from discord.ext import commands
```

Comment: That's not really related to your original question, instead of writing/copying code you don't understand you should learn more python.

Comment: I know but I don't speak English so I don't detail much.
But I was trying a lot to get to this result. I thank you very much for the help, but creating 2 questions for this does not really seem necessary, and I forgot about the import when I went from one script to another to have them separated. but the problem with await I still have it. I apologize for not writing more but I don't know English

Answer (score 1):

You called the bot as `commmands.Bot()`
but you never imported it

you just have to type `from discord.ext import commands` in the begining

Comment: I update that and this give me the error that i put in the update of my question, under the -------------- line

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you need to import commands from discord.ext
you can do this by `from discord.ext import commands`

For your second question,
you don't need to await `time.sleep()` (which is what your error says)

Also, `time.sleep()` is synchronous and will stop the entire bot from function (blocking)

Instead, use `asyncio.sleep()` which is asynchronous

simply `import asyncio`

and instead of `time.sleep(x) #x is number of seconds` use `await asyncio.sleep(x)#x is number of seconds`